# How to get return with value in Laravel view page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a redirect command in my controller. All are working fine. I have redirected with the data success.

How can I get the success value in my page. Here i have given my redirect command. In this I have posted a data as `success`. I want to get the value of `success` as `"add"`. How can I get the value.

```
return redirect('customers/create')->with('success',"add");
```

I have tried  `{{ success }}` and `{{ $success }}`. But Nothing works, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects passing params using the `->with` method simplys flashes the key/value pair to the session so presumably you could echo the value of success using:

```
{{ Session::get('success') }}
```

To check if the value is present in the session you can do the following:

```
if (Session::has('success')) {
   // do something
}
```

or to check for a specific value

```
if (Session::get('success') == 'add') {
   // success == add;  do something
}
```

or using blade syntax:

```
@if(Session::get('success') === 'add')
    <!-- Success does equal add -->
@endif
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. And is there any other ways available to get the success value?

Comment: Because I want to use this into if condition. If I use `if( ( {{Session::get('success') }} ) == 'add')` will work or not